# Concatenating images from a folder

Tags: image, matlab, file, loading, concatenation

I have a series of images saved in a folder, and I have written a short program to open two of these image files, concatenate them (preferably vertically, although for now I am trying horizontally), then save this new image to the same folder. This is what I have written so far:

```
function concatentateImages

%this is the folder where the original images are located path='/home/packremote/SharedDocuments/Amina/zEXAMPLE/';
file1 = strcat(cr45e__ch_21', '.pdf');
[image1,map1] = imread(graph1);
file2 = strcat('cr45f__ch_24', '.jpg');
[image2,map2] = imread(graph2);
image1 = ind2rgb(image1,map1);
image2 = ind2rgb(image2,map2);
image3 = cat(2,image1,image2);

%this is the directory where I want to save the new images
dircase=('/home/packremote/SharedDocuments/Amina/zEXAMPLE/');
nombrejpg=strcat(dircase, 'test', jpgext)
saveas(f, nombrejpg, 'jpg')
fclose('all');
```

However, I keep getting an error that my files do not exist, though I am certain the names are copied correctly.

I am currently using jpg files, but the format can be easily converted.

Any input on how to fix this error, or a nicer way of preforming this task is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Amina

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
[image1,map1] = imread(graph1);
```

and

```
[image2,map2] = imread(graph2);
```

by

```
[image1,map1] = imread(file1);
```

and

```
[image2,map2] = imread(file2);
```

---

Also check that you are in the right working directory.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @Simon, you also need to change

```
file1 = strcat(cr45e__ch_21', '.pdf');
```

to

```
file1 = strcat('cr45e__ch_21', '.pdf');
```

I.e. you forgot a '. Also your function doesn't seem to include a definition of `jpgext`. I expect you want a line like

```
jpgext = '.jpg';
```

Lastly, mostly a coding practice issue, but you might want to switch to using `fullfile` to build your full file path.

Also, instead of worrying about being in the correct working directory, if you use full paths you save yourself from having to keep track of what directory you're in. 
SO I would suggest:

```
dir1 ='/home/packremote/SharedDocuments/Amina/zEXAMPLE/';
file1 = fullfile(dir1, 'cr45e__ch_21.pdf');
```

etc